# How to add a module link to main menu in drupal?

Tags: drupal

How to add a module link to main menu, beside the home tab, in drupal 7/8? here is my code

```
    <?php

function api_manager_menu() {

   $items = array();

   $items['api_manager'] = array(
    'title' => 'API Manager',
    'description' => 'Manage the  lifecycle of an API',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('api_manager_form'),
    'access arguments' => user_access('administer users'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
   );

   return $items;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the `menu_name`:

```
$items['api_manager'] = array(
  'title' => 'API Manager',
  'description' => 'Manage the  lifecycle of an API',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('api_manager_form'),
  'access arguments' => user_access('administer users'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'menu_name' => 'primary-links'
);
```

See the [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) docs for more information.

Comment: I tried with 'primary-links' and 'main-menu'but doesn't work. Are the menus cached?

Comment: Yep, you'll need to clear caches any time you make changes to most hooks, and also when you add new ones

Comment: the cache of the browser or Drupal has an own caching system too?

Comment: It's Drupal's own cache; you can clear it at `admin/config/development/performance`, install the [admin menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module which gives you a quick-link, or install [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) and use `drush cc all` from the command line